# Rake db:migrate just reverted (rolled back) all the migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I just merged a branch and ran `rake db:migrate` on staging and it reverted all my migrations. (instead of migrating the new one)

I then went back to master, reloaded the db and ran migrations and again, the db got wiped out as before.

Any tips on how to debug that?

Why would `db:migrate` even rollback any migrations?

Any tips on how to maybe use a different command which tells rails only to grab new migrations and do `up` and will never roll back any migrations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `VERSION` environment variable is set then rails will migrate to that version rather than the latest. In particular since rails calls `to_i` it will migrate to version 0 if it contains a non integer value. You can check this by running `env` (to list all environment variables) or (`echo $VERSION`)

This is largely a relic from when rake didn't support passing arguments to tasks on the command line so people use to emulate them with environment variables so that you could do

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=xyz
```

Comment: You're right, `echo $VERSION` gives `0.2.0` string and I didn't put it there. Would you have any quick tip on how to do a migrate without relying on the `VERSION` for the curious?

Comment: Don't know what you can do other than unset $VERSION

Comment: Could't find where the ENV was set from. A workaround in my case was to put `ENV['VERSION'] = nil` in Rakefile with a comment.